# How does flagging a question work?

Tags: support, status-completed, flagging

I'm having issues flagging questions. I've tried doing this twice before, and I'm not sure it worked either time. I don't think it worked because it never showed up in [Tools - Flagged](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged) and I did not receive the [Citizen Patrol](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge. To test this, I flagged a post by hobodave for moderator attention a few minutes ago (sorry, hobodave). But I don't see this showing up either. Did the moderators receive the flag? In all three cases, I received the message that implied the flag had succeeded (some message like "Thanks, we'll look in to it.")

What's going on?

Comment: Interesting.  I've flagged many questions (for CW), and never received Citizen Patrol.  I also haven't ever seen it in Tools - Flagged, but they've all been dealt with.

Answer (score 3):

Your flags are working fine. When you flag something for moderator attention it is visible to moderators only. The Tools section only shows things flagged as Spam or Offensive, additionally I don't believe it shows your own flags. The Citizen Patrol badge is only given for flagging something as offensive or spam.